# Convert all items in a list to string format

Tags: spacy, huggingface-transformers

I am trying to seperate sentences (with spacy sentencizer) within a larger text format to process them in a transformers pipeline.

Unfortunately, this pipeline is not able to process the sentences correctly, since the sentences are not yet in string format after sentencizing the test. Please see the following information.

```
    string = 'The Chromebook is exactly what it was advertised to be.  It is super simple to use. The picture quality is great, stays connected to WIfi with no interruption.  Quick, lightweight yet sturdy.  I bought the Kindle Fire HD 3G and had so much trouble with battery life, disconnection problems etc. that I hate it and so I bought the Chromebook and absolutely love it. The battery life is good. Finally a product that lives up to its hype!'

    #Added the sentencizer model to the classification package, so all the sentences in the summary texts of the reviews are being disconnected from each other
import spacy

nlp = spacy.load("en_core_web_sm")

doc = nlp(string)

sentences = list(doc.sents)
sentences
```

This leads to the following list:

```
[The Chromebook is exactly what it was advertised to be.,
It is super simple to use.,
The picture quality is great, stays connected to WIfi with no interruption.,
Quick, lightweight yet sturdy.,
I bought the Kindle Fire HD 3G and had so much trouble with battery life, disconnection problems etc.,
that I hate it,
and so I bought the Chromebook and absolutely love it.,
The battery life is good.,
Finally a product that lives up to its hype!]
```

When I provide this list to the following pipline, I get this error: ValueError:  `args[0]`: The Chromebook is exactly what it was advertised to be. have the wrong format. The should be either of type `str` or type `list`

```
    #Now in this line the list of reviews are being processed into triplets
from transformers import pipeline

triplet_extractor = pipeline('text2text-generation', model='Babelscape/rebel-large', tokenizer='Babelscape/rebel-large')

model_output = triplet_extractor(sentences, return_tensors=True, return_text=False)

extracted_text = triplet_extractor.tokenizer.batch_decode([x["generated_token_ids"] for x in model_output])
print("\n".join(extracted_text))
```

Therefore, can someone please indicate how I can convert all the sentences in the 'sentences' list to string format?

Looking forward for the response. : )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your sentences are Span objects. You can convert them to strings by using `sentence.text`, so `[ss.text for ss in sentences]` for all of them.

What is `triplet_extractor`? You don't explain it anywhere.

Comment: Thank you for the comment, already found a solution. Triplet extractor is a transformer for extracting triplets.